# What are the dangers of gzipping everything?

Tags: security, nginx, compression, gzip

I have the following nginx conf:

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length  1000;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types "*";
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
```

I used to have `gzip_types gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss image/x-icon application/vnd.api+json;`, but that wasn't working for me according to [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev-.skyforge.co%2Fhome%2F) for some reason.

My questions is this - is there any disadvantage to gzipping everything? Of course it's good to compress js, css, and html. It's also probably good to compress json, images, and other media-ish files.

However, we do proxy websockets on this connection. I'd imagine the min_length bit would take care of most of that, but are there any problems that could crop up there?

Also, are there any security issues with compressing private data? [This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40562/are-there-any-risk-in-serving-static-assets-via-compressed-ssl-protocol-from-3rd) related SO mentions CRIME, which seems to indicate that compressing responses containing secrets and variable data is dangerous. I'm also reading about [BREACH](http://stacks.11craft.com/what-is-breach-how-can-we-protect-django-projects-against-it.html) which seems to be along the same lines. I'm not a security expert, so I'm not sure how worried to be about this, but we do use Django, and their advice as of August 2013 is to disable gzip entirely.

Answer (score 3):

BREACH is possible under the following circumstances:

1. Using HTTPS with HTTP compression
2. User can make a request with data that is returned in the response (like with a search box)
3. No random response padding

So if you visit an evil or compromised site, they may be able to read your bank account number or CSRF tokens.

Anyways, you can use HTTP chunked encoding to pad your responses. https://qualys.jive-mobile.com/#jive-document?content=%2Fapi%2Fcore%2Fv2%2Fposts%2F2211